# Inserting a character in the beginning of a string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, insert

I need to change all the 'PostalCode' column strings by setting a character 'A' at the beginning of the string. I've tried this:

```
UPDATE Customers SET PostalCode = STUFF(PostalCode , 0 , 1 , 'A')
```

But nothing... Any ideas?

Comment: `SET PostalCode = CONCAT('A', PostalCode )`.

Comment: Learn to tag your questions correctly.

Comment: Sorry, will watch out next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use CONCAT

```
UPDATE Customers
SET PostalCode = CONCAT('A', PostalCode )
```

Comment: Why not `A + PostalCode`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, I hope this is useful for you.

```
UPDATE Customers
SET PostalCode = 'A' + PostalCode
```